# Updating array with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am fundamentally misunderstanding React hooks, especially the useState function. Why doesn't the code below update the index of the old array, and instead set the value of trick to 1? I understand how to push a new item onto an array with React hooks, but how do you update existing values?

```
const [trick, modifyTrick] = useState([null, null, null, null]);

const identityTrick = () => {
    modifyTrick(oldTrick => oldTrick) //works
}

const updatedTrick = () => {
    modifyTrick(oldTrick => oldTrick[0] = 1) //sets the entire value of trick to 1
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update states onchange in an array of object in React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987953/how-do-i-update-states-onchange-in-an-array-of-object-in-react-hooks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide `modifyTrick` a function, the return value will be the new value of `trick`. 
The return value of your function is 1, so that's why `trick` is set to 1.

```
oldTrick[0] = 1 //this expression returns 1.
```

Modify `oldTrick` array in your `modifyTrick` function, and than return it:

```
const updatedTrick = () => {
    modifyTrick(oldTrick => {
       oldTrick[0] = 1

       return oldTrick;
    });
};
```

Comment: Why is the return value 1?

Comment: @Perplexityy The assignment operator = also returns a value: the value you just set the variable to.

Comment: Think about the expression: 'x = y = 5;'.  first y = 5 is executed, and returns the value 5.  
Because it returned the value 5, the next assignment (x = 5) is possible.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
  const updatedTrick = () => {
    modifyTrick(oldTrick => {
      let newTrick = [...oldTrick];
      newTrick[0] = 1;
      return newTrick;
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
const updateTrick = () => {
    modifyTrick(oldTrick => {
      oldTrick[0] = 1;
      return oldTrick;
    });
};
```

Comment: is the callback parameter not the reference

Comment: You're getting it wrong inside the function oldTrick is a new variable not the state one