# React.js: Assign value from state directly to TextField

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have an axios request for getting details of a transaction

```
getTransaction(batchRef) {
    return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL_GET_OUTWARD_TRANSACTION}`, {
      batchRef: batchRef,
    });
  }
```

And I call it through this service:

```
const [viewOutward, setViewOutward] = useState([]);

OutwardService.getTransaction(rowData.batchRef).then((response) => {
    setViewOutward(response.data);
});
```

It is correctly being set as a json on viewOutward state like this
e.g.
{reference: "2020091600", relatedReference: "2020091601}

Now, I want to assign these values directly onto textfields

I'm doing it this way and I'm not sure whether it is a good practice to use map on every field.

```
<TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    fullWidth
                    type="text"
                    id="reference"
                    label="Reference"
                    value={viewOutward.map((viewOutward) => viewOutward.reference)}
                    onChange={(e) => setViewOutward(e.target.value)}
                    InputProps={{
                      classes: { input: classes.textfield1 },
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      maxLength: 16,
                    }}
                  />
```

It is working however it could take a toll on the perfomance?

Can someone suggest the proper way of setting these values on the textfields using only one state. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Assuming API response:

```
[{reference: "2020091600", relatedReference: "2020091601"}, {reference: "2020091602", relatedReference: "2020091602"}, ...]
```

#### Using state in TextField

```
viewOutward.map((item, index) =>
  <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin = "normal"
        required
        autoComplete = "off"
        fullWidth
        type = "text"
        id = `${item.reference}` // if reference is unique
        label = "Reference"
        key = { index } // to identity unique for react 
        value = { item.reference } // assign value
        onChange = {(e) =>  //onchange of text assign new value to same object
                 setViewOutward(vo => 
                  vo.map(row => row.reference === item.reference
                  ? { ...row, reference: e.target.value //whatever property you can update 
                  } : row)
                 )
               }
        InputProps = {{
        classes: { input: classes.textfield1 },
      }}
        inputProps = {{
        maxLength: 16,
      }}
  />
)
```

[Adding Reference for how to update state of an array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987953/how-do-i-update-states-onchange-in-an-array-of-object-in-react-hooks)