# useState to update array of objects nested inside object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

I have state set as follows:

```
  const [groupState, setGroupState] = useState({
    groupId: uuidv4(),
    content: [],
  });
```

I want to push an object to the 'content' array but am having difficulty. I looked at this answer: [How do I update states onchange in an array of object in React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987953/how-do-i-update-states-onchange-in-an-array-of-object-in-react-hooks) but can't seem to apply it to the problem.

Currently I have:

```
setGroupState({
  ...groupState,
  ...content.push({test: 'test'})
});
```

.. but it's not working and I'm getting nowhere.

Can anyone tell me how to get this sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` mutates the array, you should create a new array like so:

```
setGroupState({
  ...groupState,
  content: [...groupState.content, {test: 'test'}],
});
```

Comment: Thanks - worked like a treat. Don't know who put the mark down there or what it was for - perfectly reasonable question. 'Research effort' is stated.