# useState not causing rerender when objects array changes *hooks*

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an object, which has a number of keys, and at each key, there is an array of objects. Each object contains an image file that I need to show to preview the image that the user has just uploaded. But it's showing the image that was uploaded the previous time (not the one that's been just uploaded)

Apparently useState doesn't immediately cause a rerender unless it sees a change in the array or object [How do I update states onchange in an array of object in React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987953/how-do-i-update-states-onchange-in-an-array-of-object-in-react-hooks)

I followed the above (and a number of similar suggestions from StackOverflow) and made a copy of the object and a copy of the array at the key but it still doesn't work

Any idea why?

```
const Form = props => {
let [images, setImages] = useState({
    bannerPicture: [],
    projectPictures: [],
    projectsPictures: [],
    thumbnailPictures: []
})
const showTempImage = (file, tempFileObj, key) => {
    const imagesCopy = {...images}
    // add this image to the end of the array at the given key
    imagesCopy[key] = [...imagesCopy[key], tempFileObj]
    setImages({...imagesCopy})
....

}
```

I just want the image to show immediately after the user uploads it

Comment: Did you check, if the key is correct?

Comment: @FireFighter key is definitely correct, yes

Comment: Am I right that the only thing which stopping your progress is that's not rerendering UI even if your state updated? Or your state is not updating after showTempImage?

Comment: @SabitRakhim good question. So I console.log(images) after setImages, and it doesn't show a change in images nor does the UI rerender. But if I upload another image, it shows the previous image that was uploaded both in the UI and the images state

Comment: Can you try to add console.log() before setImages and assign something like `const newImages = {...imagesCopy}`, then show it. The difference is that state is async and I think it's not work as single source of truth

Comment: You need to use `useEffect` hook with `images` as a dependency, and perform the actions after uploading the image inside the `useEffect` body.

Comment: @SabitRakhim it console.logs() nothing until I upload another image

Comment: @BlackMath I tried adding images as a dependency to useEffect before but it didn't work. How would I call useEffect with images as a dependency from within the same component? I know how to do it if it were coming from props but this is within the same component

Comment: @hillybob991 `useEffect(() => {//somelogic}, [images])`

Answer (score 0):

Do it from your `async` function.

I'm assuming you'll only show the image after the upload is complete.

```js
const mockUploadApi = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("uploadedImage");
    },1000);
  });
};


const App = () => {

  const [state,setState] = React.useState({
    status: "IDLE",
    image: ""
  });
  
  const uploadImage = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      status: "UPLOADING"
    }));

    // THIS SHOULD USE await BUT THE SNIPPET DOES NOT ALLOW IT
    // SO I'M USING .then()
    
    mockUploadApi().then((uploadedImage) => {
      setState({
        status: "IDLE",
        image: uploadedImage
      });
    });
  };

  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        status: {state.status}
      </div>
      <div>
        image: {state.image || "no image"}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={uploadImage}>
          Upload
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```