# React form handle multiple selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to handle multiple selection, due to the fact that I use State and everytime I select an option, a new item is added, but I need to store all the results in an array.

Please find bellow my code:

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

return (
    <div className="create">
      <h2>Add a New Rating</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Review title:</label>
        <label>Rating:</label>
       

        <select
          style={{ height: "170px" }}
          className="multiple"
          multiple={true}
          value={categories}
          onChange={(e) => setCategories(e.target.value)} #<-- here, I don't know how to store more items in the initial array
        >
          {data.categories.data.map((category) => (
            <option value={category.id} key={category.id}>
              {category.attributes.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <button>Add Review</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I manage to implement the multiple selection in this react app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update states \`onChange\` in an array of object in React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987953/how-do-i-update-states-onchange-in-an-array-of-object-in-react-hooks)

Comment: Please, only use tags that are relevant to your question. Here, your question is about React in JavaScript, not about either strapi or GraphQL even if your project uses those.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this one:

```
  const updateFieldChanged =  e => {

    console.log('property name: '+ e.target.name);
    let newArr = [...categories]; // copying the old datas array
    newArr.push(e.target.value); // replace e.target.value with whatever you want to change it to
  
    setCategories(newArr);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the .concat method. It returns a new array as not manipulated state.

setCategories(categories.concat(e.target.name));