# how to set state for the object in handlechange event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```js
const [tableModel, setTableModel] = React.useState<Itable>(
    {
        columnList: [
            {
                index: Math.random(),
                ColumnName: "",
                DataType: "",
                ColumnUnique: "",
                ForeignKey: "",
                EncryptedYn: ""
            },
        ],
        schemaName: "",
        tableName: ""
    }
)
```

I want to update the state for schemaName and tableName alone in one function and in another, I have to update the state for the column list. please help

Comment: What is your attempt on solving this? Where's your problem?

Comment: i dont know how to update

Comment: See for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55988017/1893976